# Unable to generate word output in DITA-OT if the input argument has an UNC path

Tags: dita-ot

I am trying to execute DITA-OT commands using JAVA application.
My DITA-OT sits at a separate location (application server WILDFLY) and the input files are on some other server. I'm trying to generate a word output but I'm getting an error "uri has an authority component"

The following is my command that I am trying to execute

```
cmd /C dita --input="\\<MACHINE_NAME>\FileServer\temp\dita-ot_00002_00001059387483239798817621042\00002_0000081949" --output="\\<MACHINE_NAME>\FileServer\temp\dita-ot_00002_00001059387483239798817621042\sc_report.docx" --format=docx
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an issue on the DITA OT issues list:
https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/issues/3673

Maybe in the meantime you can map the UNC path to a local drive and publish this way.